# Replicating Jetbrains Exposed Star Wars Example in IntelliJ Scratch file

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin-exposed, scratch-file

I am following [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO) wiki to learn kotlin [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed). It contains an example of `Referencing` using Star Wars data. I would like to create a scratch and/or console file in IntelliJ which reproduces this simple example. However When I try to run the code I get errors (see below). Is there something I am missing here?

Note that when there is only one table `StarWarsFilm` i am able to successfully add the record `theLastJedi`. The below errors only show when i have added `referencedOn` links between the tables.

### Errors

```
error: unresolved reference: UserRating

val ratings by UserRating referrersOn UserRatings.film

error: unresolved reference: UserRatings

val ratings by UserRating referrersOn UserRatings.film

error: unresolved reference: StarWarsFilm

var film by StarWarsFilm referencedOn UserRatings.film // use referencedOn for normal references

error: unresolved reference: starWars

starWars()

error: unresolved reference: StarWarsFilm

val theLastJedi = StarWarsFilm.new {
```

### Entered into an IntelliJ scratch console

```kotlin
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntEntity
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntEntityClass
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.EntityID
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.IntIdTable
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SchemaUtils
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction


fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit =
    io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
object StarWarsFilms : IntIdTable() {
    val sequelId = integer("sequel_id").uniqueIndex()
    val name = varchar("name", 50)
    val director = varchar("director", 50)
}

class StarWarsFilm(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<StarWarsFilm>(StarWarsFilms)

    var sequelId by StarWarsFilms.sequelId
    var name by StarWarsFilms.name
    var director by StarWarsFilms.director
    val ratings by UserRating referrersOn UserRatings.film
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
object Users : IntIdTable() {
    val name = varchar("name", 50)
}

class User(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<User>(Users)

    var name by Users.name
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
object UserRatings : IntIdTable() {
    val value = long("value")
    val film = reference("film", StarWarsFilms)
    val user = reference("user", Users)
}

class UserRating(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<UserRating>(UserRatings)

    var value by UserRatings.value
    var film by StarWarsFilm referencedOn UserRatings.film // use referencedOn for normal references
    var user by User referencedOn UserRatings.user
}


object DatabaseFactory {

    fun init() {
        fun hikari(): HikariDataSource {
            val config = HikariConfig()
            config.driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver" // 1
            config.jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql:star_wars?user=postgres&password=xxxx" // 2
            config.maximumPoolSize = 3
            config.isAutoCommit = false
            config.transactionIsolation = "TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ"
            config.validate()

            return HikariDataSource(config)
        }

        Database.connect(hikari())

        transaction {
            SchemaUtils.create(
                StarWarsFilms,
                UserRatings,
                Users
            )
        }

    }

}

@Suppress("unused")
fun Application.module() {
    DatabaseFactory.init()
    starWars()
}

fun Application.starWars() {
    transaction {
        val theLastJedi = StarWarsFilm.new {
            name = "The Last Jedi"
            sequelId = 36
            director = "Rian Johnson"
        }
        val someUser = User.new {
            name = "Some User"
        }
        val rating1 = UserRating.new {
            value = 9
            user = someUser
            film = theLastJedi
        }
        val rating2 = UserRating.new {
            value = 6
            user = someUser
            film = theLastJedi
        }

    }
}



println("end")
```